# Laravel 5 Eloquent View Blade com Foreign Key?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Trying to get property 'nome' of non-object

Tenho uma relação de Fornecedores e Pagamentos, e estou usando a seguinte sintaxe para recuperar o nome do Fornecedor através da chave estrangeira do pagamentos.

```
<td>{{$pagamento->fornecedor_id->nome}}</td>
```

**Tabela Pagamentos**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pagamentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('data_pag');
        $table->decimal('valor');            
        $table->string('plano_contas', 20);
        $table->integer('fornecedor_id')->unsigned()->nullable();      
        $table->foreign('fornecedor_id')->references('id')->on('fornecedores')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('set null');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Tabela Fornecedores**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fornecedores', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome', 55);
        $table->string('cnpj', 18)->unique();
        $table->string('endereco', 44);            
        $table->integer('numero');                
        $table->string('cep', 9);            
        $table->string('complemento', 44)->nullable();            
        $table->string('bairro', 44);            
        $table->string('celular', 14)->nullable();              
        $table->string('telefone', 13);              
        $table->string('cidade', 44);              
        /*$table->integer('city_id')->unsigned()->nullable();      
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('set null');  */      
        $table->string('estado', 2);                      
        $table->string('email', 44)->unique();                      
        $table->string('inscri_estadual', 44)->unique()->nullable();                      
        $table->string('inscri_municipal', 44)->unique()->nullable();                         
        $table->timestamps();
    });


}
```

**Controller Pagamentos**

```
public function index(){
    $pagamentos = Pagamento::all();
    $fornecedores = Fornecedor::all();

    return view('pagamentos.pagamento', 
       compact('pagamentos','fornecedores'));         
}
```

**Model Pagamento**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Fornecedor;

class Pagamento extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'pagamentos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'data_pag', 'valor', 'fornecedor_id','plano_contas',
    ];



    public function fornecedores(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Fornecedor');
    }
}
```

**Model Fornecedores**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Pagamento;


class Fornecedor extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'fornecedores';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'cnpj', 'endereco', 'numero', 'cep', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'celular', 'telefone', 'cidade', 'estado', 'email', 'inscri_estadual', 'inscri_municipal',
    ];


    public function pagamento(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pagamento');
    }
}
```

---

```
{{ dd($pagamento) }}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@foreach($pagamentos as $pagamento)
                            {{ dd($pagamentos) }}
                            <tr class="item{{$pagamentos->id}}">
                                <td>{{$pagamento->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$pagamento->data_pag}}</td>
                                <td>{{$pagamento->valor}}</td>
                                <td>{{$pagamento->fornecedor_id->nome}}</td>
                                <td>{{$pagamento->plano_contas}}</td>
                                <td><button class="btnOpenUpdatePag btn btn-
info" data-id="{{$pagamento->id}}" data-data_pag="{{$pagamento->data_pag}}" 
data-valor="{{$pagamento->valor}}" data-pessoa="{{$pagamento->fornecedor_id-
>nome}}" data-plano_contas="{{$pagamento->plano_contas}}"> <span class="fa 
fa-pencil"></span></button>`
                                    <button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$pagamento->id}}" data-data_pag="{{$pagamento->data_pag}}" data-valor="{{$pagamento->valor}}" data-pessoa="{{$pagamento->fornecedor_id->nome}}" data-plano_contas="{{$pagamento->plano_contas}}" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

**Pagamentos com Id dos fornecedores fazendo o relacionamento correto!**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PRINT TABELA FORNECEDORES**

> [image: print tabela fornecedores]

Comment: Na verdade é bem simples.... no seu model você possui o relacionamento `class Pagamento extends Model
{... public function fornecedores(){` então na sua view, basta você acessar a função `fornecedores()` assim: `<td>{{ $pagamento->fornecedores()->nome }}</td>`

Comment: Esse erro dá porque o campo `fornecedor_id` não é um objeto, e sim um integer

Comment: Usando desta forma eu recebo o seguinte erro 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$nome (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Esystemm\resources\views\pagamentos\pagamento.blade.php)"

Comment: Para facilitar, na sua view, faça: `<td>{{ dd($pagamento) }}</td>`

E ponha o resultado aqui

Comment: Um print do resultado no edit da pergunta

Comment: @GabrielAlves na sua view use dessa maneira, $pagamento->fornecedores()->get()->first()->nome. se você usar apenas o fornecedor() se refere ao QB.

Comment: Trying to get property 'nome' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Esystemm\resources\views\pagamentos\pagamento.blade.php) 

Mesmo erro @arllondias , eu acredito que esteja tudo correto, a foreign key esta funcionando eu acho que o problema esta no eloquent eu segui o material do laravel sobre HasMany e BelongsTo e não esta funcionando

Comment: No seu banco de dados, todos os pagamentos que está buscando tem fornecedores cadastrados?

Comment: @arllondias Sim! E a foreign key criada pela migration esta fazendo o relacionamento correto. É a primeira vez que faço isso com laravel...

Comment: @arllondias Segue o print no edit!

Comment: vou tentar simular aqui, porque ao meu ver a grosso modo, está correto

Comment: pode tirar um print da tabela de fornecedores tbm?

Comment: @arllondias segue o print

Comment: Bom aqui funcionou normalmente, eu vi que no seu código, tem mais de 1 lugar que acessa fornecedor(). tente trocar todos para fornecedor()->get()->first() e o atributo que você precisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, assim como falei nos comentários, a maneira de acessar o atributo está incorreta. tente dessa forma (coloquei a table so para mostrar no print):

```
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Data Pag</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Fornecedor</th>
            <th>Plano Contas</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($pagamentos as $pagamento)
        <tr data-data_pag="{{$pagamento->data_pag}}" data-valor="{{$pagamento->valor}}"
            data-pessoa="{{$pagamento->fornecedor()->get()->first()->nome}}"
            data-plano_contas="{{$pagamento->plano_contas}}">
            <td>{{$pagamento->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$pagamento->data_pag}}</td>
            <td>{{$pagamento->valor}}</td>
            <td>{{$pagamento->fornecedor()->get()->first()->nome}}</td>
            <td>{{$pagamento->plano_contas}}</td>
        <tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Encontrei o erro, eu estava usando o nome da função fornecedores no model e usando fornecedores() na view também e por algum motivo estava dando errado, troquei o nome da função no model para fornecedor() e na view para fornecedor() e agora esta correto! Trouxe os dados, muito obrigado!